# How to change java version and web version on org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml under .settings dir of eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications

I want to modify org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml under .settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <faceted-project>
    <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
    <installed facet="java" version="1.5"/>
    <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.3"/>
    <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

I would like to change the above java version to 1.6 and web to 3.0; I could change it manually by opening in a notepad, but, after that from eclipse (kepler) if I try to update from Maven -> update project, it says error "Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.3."

How can I make maven to know that I want to create web app with version 3.0 and specified java version.

I'm creating maven project (archetype as webapp).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Modified web.xml to have below:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
   <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

and add following plugins as maven 3 wants to have compiler

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: +1. Its too sad to see 2900 persons who most probably benefited from your solution and none of them cared to up-vote.

Answer (score -1):

try to check and uncheck web module, it works with me after I did this